# How to hide password characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, user-input

I created a simple program in which I added username and password entry (no GUI) by using an `if else` conditional expression.
When I type the username in program, it appears as simple text, and that's ok.
But when I type in the password field, it also appears as simple text.
I want the password instead to display `*` like all login prompts.

How do I change the password field to show => `*****`?

```
usr = (str(input('USERNAME : ')))
if usr == 'python':
  password = (str(input('PASSWORD : ')))
  if password == 'root':
    print ('login succesfull')
  else:
    print ('wrong password')
else:
  print ('wrong username')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass), a function which *hides* the user input:

```
 import getpass

 password = getpass.getpass()
 print(password)

 mypass = getpass.getpass("PASSWORD : ")
```