# How to hide specific command line arguments while passed to a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to hide specific command line argument while passed in Python script?
I have special requirement where I need to pass user password in Python script as a command line argument but it should not be exposed.

I can not use getops to ask user password at runtime.

Comment: If you really mean to pass that as a command line argument when calling the Python program then this is not a Python question but depending on your OS and the terminal you use. Anyway, I doubt that is possible. How will it know you're about to enter a password? Best you can do is take the password as regular input and hide it, for example: [How to hide password characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45686752/6045800)

Comment: Store the password in an environment variable, then access it from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide password characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686752/how-to-hide-password-characters)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't mark this as a duplicate because I believe the OP means passing the password while calling the Python in the command line, i.e. `python main.py -username tomer -password xyz1234`. While I doubt it is even possible, I don't think this is a duplicate